# HTMLHelper, generating parameter of type "Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression" out of property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, html-helper

I'm writing an HTML Helper for an editor. The idea is to get properties from the Model with attributes AutoGenerateField and build a table, each line of which contains a name of a field (also from the attribute) and a TextBox or a CheckBox containing actual value of the field.

I have a problem with HTMLHelper. Since I send the whole model to the helper and not one value, I cannot use methods such as TextBoxFor, as they need parameter, such as

```
"Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression".
```

I'm using reflexion and I tried to send the property instead, still VisualStudio considers this as incorrect usage.

Below is simplified method for my HtmlHelper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GenerateEditor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
{
    var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
    var result = String.Empty;

    //generating container, etc ...

    foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var attr = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DisplayAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault(); 
        if (attr == null) continue;
        var autoGenerate = ((DisplayAttribute)attr).AutoGenerateField;
        if(autoGenerate)
        {
           //here I'm building the html string 
           //My problem is in the line below:
           var r = htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(property); 
        }
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using the non-lambda overloads. : `InputExtensions.TextBox()`

```
if(autoGenerate)
{
   //here I'm building the html string 
   //My problem is in the line below:
   var r = htmlHelper.TextBox(property.Name); 
}
//not sure what you do with r from here...
```

If I'm not mistaken the `name` attribute of the form element is set to the property name even when you use the lambda version of the function so this should do the same thing.

I will try and verify what the lambda function does, you might be able to do the same since you have the `TModel` with you.

---

**Update**

From a **quick look** of things inside the source code of [InputExtensions.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8e5a8db920443ba7d6b491764f5298e0f5e46332#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs), TextBoxFor calls eventually calls `InputHelper()` which eventually calls `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(LambdaExpression expression)` inside [ExpressionHelper.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8e5a8db920443ba7d6b491764f5298e0f5e46332#src/System.Web.Mvc/ExpressionHelper.cs) which from the cursory looks of things gets the `member.Name` for the name html attribute on the input element.

I can't quite verify it right now because I'm not on windows but I think the non-lambda function should suit your need. Do tell me how it goes?